# Extending SQLiteStatement, is there a tested wrapper class available?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The class cannot subclass the final class [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) cannot be extended.

That together with the fact that java does not support extension methods brings me here. 
There does not seem to be any smooth way to do extensions for that class.

I do not have the time to write and test a class that wraps the class SQLiteStatement. I'm thus asking if there is a trusted wrapper class out there for this?

What I've done right now is a class with methods that I send the reference to SQLiteStatement and the values I want to add to the SQLiteStatement but that is not as smooth as extending the class.

Comment: The Android SQLite API has many design issues and it's not very extensible. However, it being open source, consider whether forking it from AOSP is an option for you.

Comment: Yes I thought about it but then I figure I need to keep an eye on new releases of it and maintain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lack of better alternatives or if none else answers my question this will be my solution.

This is the start of a class with the methods this far to avoid repeated null check statements etc.

```
public class SQLiteStatementExtension  {

    public static void BindNullable(SQLiteStatement statement, int index, String value)
    {
        if(value == null){
            statement.bindNull(index);
        } else {
            statement.bindString(index, value); 
        }
    }

    public static void BindNullable(SQLiteStatement statement, int index, Calendar value)
    {
        if(value == null){
            statement.bindNull(index);
        } else {
            statement.bindLong(index, value.getTimeInMillis()); 
        }
    }

    public static void BindNullable(SQLiteStatement statement, int index, byte[] value)
    {
        if(value == null){
            statement.bindNull(index);
        } else {
            statement.bindBlob(index, value);   
        }
    }

    public static void Bind(SQLiteStatement satement, int index, boolean value) {
        satement.bindLong(index, value ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```